# mount ssd disk on new acquired server

Tags: mount, ssd, raid

I have just acquired a new 3x 120Go SSD server (within [soyoustart](http://www.soyoustart.com/ma/cpu/) Soft Raid), but I can only see/use one SSD disk! Should I mount the other 2 disks ? What should be the new content of `fstab` file ? here is some useful information

```
$ lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda           111.8G            
├─sda1 ext4    19.5G /          
├─sda2 ext4    90.3G /home      
└─sda3 swap       2G [SWAP]     swap-sda3
sdb           111.8G            
sdc           111.8G 

$ fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000d7855

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        4096    40962047    20478976   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        40962048   230338559    94688256   83  Linux
/dev/sda3       230338560   234432511     2046976   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/sdc: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdc doesn't contain a valid partition table

$ cat /etc/fstab
/dev/sda1   /   ext4    errors=remount-ro,relatime,discard  0   1
/dev/sda2   /home   ext4    defaults,relatime,discard   1   2
/dev/sda3   swap    swap    defaults    0   0 proc      /proc   proc    defaults        0   0
sysfs       /sys    sysfs   defaults        0   0 devtmpfs  /dev    devtmpfs    rw  0   0
```

Comment: It's a new server, I don't care about any data! how can I know if the 2 disks are part of Raid system ? How can I disable this Raid  or at least keep only one of the tow as Raid ?

Answer (score 2):

Only one drive (sda) seems to contain a partition table, so there's nothing mountable on the other drives (sdb and sdc). They may be set up to be part of a RAID, which may obfuscate the partition table. If you don't care about the data they may hold, just repartition and format them.

I'm not sure how to inspect the current RAID status of a disk, but since you don't care about the data, I don't see a reason to investigate that. Just create new partition tables, partitions, logical volumes, and file systems on them as you see fit.